# Use of multiple contexts of React Context API in a class component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to know how we can use context API for multiple contexts from a class component.
In single use, we simply do,

```
  class ContextConsumer extends Component { 
      static contextType = MyContext;

      componentDidMount() {
          console.log(this.context);
      }
   }
```

Note:
I know how multiple contexts can be used in a functional component. But want to know using in a class component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53346462/9787887 does it answer your question? (One person suggested that you can merge 2 contexts into 1 before assign to your class).

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that is not the answer. I want to know a direct method.