# (React.js) Nested useContext (global > small components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I wonder what problem could occur by nesting useContext?

for example, I have these files

```
app.js
  -components
    -BookLists.js
    -BookReview.js
    -Comments.js
  -pages
    -Main.js
    -Viewer.js
    -Auth.js
app.js
```

And I need context provider globally and individually for the smaller components

such as

```
<context.Provider>
   <Main />
</context.Provider>
```

```
<scrollerHistory.Provider>
  <BookList />
</scrollerHistory.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Context API provides consuming multiple contexts. Check the following for more detail.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts

[React multiple contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346462/react-multiple-contexts/53346541)

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you! Can't believe I couldn't find these!