# cart count is not getting updated properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd, react-state-management

screeen record of the issue: https://streamable.com/ofn42v

it is working fine in local but once deployed to production(vercel), it is not working. i have tried sooo many different things like having a separate state in cart, `useEffect` with `totalQuantity` in dependency array and nothing seems to work. Ideally when the `totalQuantity` inside the context is updated, the components using it should rerender as mentioned in [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) which is happening from `n` to `2` except for `1`. can someone please help :(

my code for the cart icon in nav bar:

```
function Cart(props) {
  const { enableCart, totalQuantity } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <>
      {enableCart ? (
        <Link href="/cart" passHref>
          <a aria-label="Shopping cart" title="Shopping cart">
            <Badge count={totalQuantity} offset={[0, 5]}>
              <ShoppingCartIcon className="w-7 h-7" />
            </Badge>
          </a>
        </Link>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

Update quantity - code in appContext:

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
export const AppProvider = (props) => {

  const [cartItems, updateCart] = useState([]);
  const [totalQuantity, setTotalQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["cart"]);
  const cookieCart = cookies.cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    cartOperations();
  }, []);

  const calculateAmountQuantity = (items) => {
    let totalCount = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    items.forEach((item) => {
      totalCount += item.quantity;
      totalPrice += item.price * item.quantity;
      setTotalAmount(totalPrice);
      setTotalQuantity(totalCount);
    });
  };

  const cartOperations = async (items) => {
    if (items !== undefined) {
      updateCart([...items]);
      calculateAmountQuantity(items);
    } else if (cookieCart !== undefined) {
      updateCart([...cookieCart]);
      calculateAmountQuantity(cookieCart);
    } else {
      updateCart([]);
      setTotalAmount(0);
      setTotalQuantity(0);
    }
  };
  
  const addItem = (item) => {
    let items = cartItems;
    let existingItem;
    if (items) existingItem = items.find((i) => i.id === item.id);

    if (!existingItem) {
      items = [
        ...(items || []),
        Object.assign({}, item, {
          quantity: 1,
        }),
      ];
      updateCart([...items]);
      setTotalAmount(totalAmount + item.price * 1);
      setTotalQuantity(totalQuantity + 1);
    } else {
      const index = items.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id);
      items[index] = Object.assign({}, item, {
        quantity: existingItem.quantity + 1,
      });
      updateCart([...items]);
      setTotalAmount(totalAmount + existingItem.price);
      setTotalQuantity(totalQuantity + 1);
    }
    saveCartToCookie(items);
    saveCartToStrapi(items);
  };
```

i am storing the cart content in cookie.

code for `AppContext` is [here in github](https://github.com/Gogulaanand/website/blob/main/frontend/context/AppContext.js), full `nav bar` [code](https://github.com/Gogulaanand/website/blob/main/frontend/components/index/nav.js)

Live url: https://sunfabb.com

Goto Products, add few items to cart, then try removing one by one from the cart page. (i have enabled react profiler in prod as well)

**EDIT:** This issue is completely specific to antd library. I was able to debug further based on the below 2 answers and there is nothing wrong with react context or re-render. i tried using a custom badge for cart and it is working perfectly fine. Yet to fix the antd issue though. I can go with custom one, but antd's badge is better with some animations.

Comment: A quick thing I’d suggest you to try is use `setTotalQuantity(value => value - 1)` instead. My guess is that this is a stale closure probelm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but doesnt seem to work here @hackape. Deployed the change you suggested [here](https://website-9hnqgff3w-gogulaanand.vercel.app/products)

Comment: Also, stale closure was something new to me & looked it up. Based on the explanation [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), it should not have worked for removing items from n...2 but here only last item in cart is causing problem. how can it become stale at that point alone ?

Comment: It’s just a blind guess. Your app is quite complex and I can’t spot problem at this point. But I can tell that a) it’s vulnerable to stale closure problem, and b) I wouldn’t manage `totalQuantity` this way. It can be derived/computed from `cartItems`, these is no point to manually set its value, it adds unnecessary complexity and potentially introduce bug.

Comment: `const [totalPrice, totalQuantity] = cartItems.reduce(([price, quantity], item) => [price + item.price, quantity + item.quantity], [0, 0])`

Comment: In `calculateAmountQuantity`, `setTotalAmount`and `setTotalQuantity` should not be called from within `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the renders and from seeing that after a refresh the cart shows as empty as should be, it's probably a lifecycle issue.

I'd suggest creating another `useEffect` hook that listens to `totalQuantity` or `totalAmount` (logically the bigger of the two though by the state values it looks either should be fine) and in the hook call change the cart icon based on the updated sum

EDIT:

misread your inter-component imports, because Cart (from `components/index/nav.js`) should **listen** for changes from the `context.provider` you would use a [context.consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) on `Cart` with the `totalQuantity` value (not just with importing the variable from the context as that rides on the application rendering from other reasons)

see example in [consumer docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346462/react-multiple-contexts), and check [this GitHub issues page](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14759) for other's detailed journey while encountering this issue more directly

Comment: i have tried the same, but not working. check [this](https://github.com/Gogulaanand/website/blob/cart-badge-fix/frontend/components/index/nav.js#L13)

Comment: not like this, since nothing actually should change there's no reason the virtual DOM would change, hence, trigger something else **in the page itself** like rerendering the cart icon

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you. Trigger something else in the page, meaning ? we can rerender only when something changes right ? (in this case, count). do you mean force rerender the cart icon ?

Comment: thanks a lot for resouces. learnt few things. i figured out that the issue is not with react at all. it is with antd library's badge component. not sure why it is not working though

Comment: Marvelous to hear ☺️

Comment: If our back and forth was helpful I'd appreciate you giving me the bounty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236927/discussion-between-rgog-and-noam-yizraeli).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @hackape, when setting the value of state to something that depends on the previous value of that state, you should pass a function to the setState instead of a value.

So instead of `setTotalQuantity(totalQuantity + 1);`, you should say `setTotalQuantity(previousQuantity => previousQuantity + 1);`.

This is the safe way of doing that, so for example if we are trying to do it twice simultaneously, they both get taken into account, instead of both using the same initial `totalQuantity`.

Other thing that I would think about changing is that you are setting those quantities and amounts in multiple places, and relying on the previous value. So if it goes out of sync once, it's out of sync also on the next action, and so on.

You could use the `useEffect` hook for this. Every time the cartItems change, calculate those values again, and do that based only on the new cartItems array, not on the old values.

Something like this for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTotalAmount(cartItems.reduce((total, currentItem) => total + (currentItem.price * currentItem.quantity), 0));
  setTotalQuantity(cartItems.reduce((total, currentItem) => total + currentItem.quantity, 0));
}, [cartItems]);
```

Or if you prefer calling it like you do now, I would still replace the value with the reduce from my example, so it get's calculated based on the whole cart instead of previous value.

A shopping cart is usually something that contains less than 100 entries, so there is really no need to worry about the performance.

Comment: regarding the use of reduce in useEffect, its a nice and clean solution but it is causing an infinite loop of rerenders. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/7KzZBVi). As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57854008/8803194), it seems using map/reduce in useEffect will reset the state and the suggestion is to move it outside useEffect.